# Where can I find a good Pokemon database file?

Tags: database

Im developing a Pokedex with Android and I need a good and complete Database file with all Pokemon and related data (abilities , moves , evolutions , natures , breeding , items.. ) . Is there any decent .db file ?

Answer (score 1):

[Searching for Pokemon database](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=pokemon+database) I stumbled upon [pokemondb.net](https://pokemondb.net/pokedex/all). However, as they outline in their [FAQ](https://pokemondb.net/about#faq) you cannot re-use that data.

They do point to some other resources might be useful for you:

- [Veekun's database](https://github.com/veekun/pokedex/tree/master/pokedex/data/csv)
- [PokeAPI](https://pokeapi.co/about.html)